# Spring Cloud Dataflow Kubernetes - Stream External IP

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

Name: spring-cloud-dataflow-server
Version: 2.2.0.RELEASE

Deployed a simple stream http|log and while deploy from dashboard set following for the 'http' app

spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.createLoadBalancer=true
app.http.spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.createLoadBalancer=true

but still don't get External IP automatically. Any help appreciated.

*Note:* If manually change the type from ClusterIP to LoadBalancer in Http Service directly from kubernetes dashboard it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying a stream with deployer properties, you'd have to use the `deployer` prefix.

For instance, consider the following stream.

> stream create task-stream --definition "http | task-launcher-dataflow --spring.cloud.dataflow.client.server-uri=http://192.168.99.139:30578 --platform-name=fooz"

When deploying it, you can supply the deployer property to create a load-balancer for a particular app, which in this case is the `http-source` application.

> stream deploy task-stream --properties "deployer.http.kubernetes.createLoadBalancer=true"

When deploying the same stream from the Dashboard, though, you'd have to supply it in the freeform textbox in the deployment page.

```
deployer.http.kubernetes.createLoadBalancer=true
```

Comment: Thank you, Sabby. Your suggestion works - either including "kubernetes.createLoadBalancer" and setting it true for "http" app under deployment properties in Dashboard builder tab (or)  entering deployer.http.kubernetes.createLoadBalancer=true in the freeform